# Jquery function is needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following code add div on click button. But I want to add classes to all divs in code with id(1), id(2) etc without clicking position. Is this possible.

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var $sparkLines = $('.sparkLines');
        $("#sparkLineContainer").append('<div id="id' + ($sparkLines.length + 1) + '" class="sparkLines">Some Stuff Here</div>');

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sparkLineContainer">
        <div class="sparkLines" id="id1">Some stuff here</div>
        <div class="sparkLines" id="id2">Some stuff here</div>
        <div class="sparkLines" id="id3">Some stuff here</div>
    </div>

<button>Add Spark Line</button>
```

Actually I want to add class to all divs but with id1, id2, id3.

For example:

```
<div class="addclass" id="id1"></div>
<div class="addclass" id="id2"></div>
```

Comment: Right now your coding is working fine. what is the meaning of "without clicking position"?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: Have a look at wildcard selectors - you can add a class to all ids starting with "id" like this (not tested but close) `$("[id^=id]").addClass('className')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can do that using a counter on your function, Let me use Jquery on this.

```
function addDiv(){
  var counter =0;
  $('id').append('div id="' + counter +'"');
  counter  = counter + 1;

}
```

This should work.